# how to use dd to read and seek different block size

Tags: linux, bash, unix, dd

I have a situation where i have to read sparse file. This file is having data at specific offset. Now i want to achieve.
1) Read 3 blocks(custom sizes) from the given offset
2) offset need to be seek using 1M

So, i am trying below command but not successful. I am reading more contents for sure.

```
dd if=a_Sparse_file_ofSIZe_1024M of=/dev/null ibs=1M skip=512 obs=262144 count=3
```

skip 512M of blocks and read from 512M+1 th offset using block of 256K for 3 counts.

skip always should be in MBs and count blocks are variable.
I am sure i am reading more data. Can someone please correct me.

Comment: are there any constraints on the second block size?

Answer (score 3):

You can always string 2 `dd`s together, the first one to skip and the second one to read your actual data:

```
dd if=a_Sparse_file_ofSIZe_1024M bs=1M skip=N | dd bs=262144 count=3
```

Comment: yes good ides. but still data read is more that just 3 count of 256K.

Comment: You could add a count of `1` to the first `dd`, if you are that worried. I am guessing you have a slow disk...

Comment: Oops! i didn't bother possible slow disks is the cause :(. blocks are reporting higher than expected. need to try your suggestion on faster disks. A Big Thanks you.!

Comment: Thanks i will try that too. @MarkSetchell is correct, some issue with slowness of disks is surely disrupting something.

Answer (score 1):

The `count` parameter seems to be based on `ibs`, so the `obs` value does not matter here. As your `obs` value is four times smaller than `ibs`, I would suggest to set `bs=256K` and just multiply `skip` value by four: `skip=2048`.

Comment: ibs must be 1M as skip will be based on this right?. I need to skip blocks in MB only. but while reading, i need to make sure i read specified counts of variable block sizes.